# Parse XML Without Knowing The Schema

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, xml-parsing

Using SQL Server 2008 I want to convert this following XML into the table structure below. The XML is supplied by a third party and cannot be changed, and other than the recordid each table has an unknown list of elements.

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '
<NewDataSet>
    <Table1>
        <recordid>1</recordid>
        <Q2_1>aaaa</Q2_1>
        <Q2_2>bbbb</Q2_2>
    </Table1>
    <Table1>
        <recordid>2</recordid>
        <R2_1>eeee</R2_1>
        <R2_2>ffff</R2_2>
    </Table1>
    <Table1>
        <recordid>3</recordid>
        <R2_1>iiii</R2_1>
        <Q2_2>jjjj</Q2_2>
    </Table1>
</NewDataSet>';
```

sample table

```
recordid                ElementName                 Value
----------------------------------------------------------
1                       Q2_1                        aaaa
1                       Q2_2                        bbbb
2                       R2_1                        eeee
2                       R2_2                        ffff
3                       R2_1                        iiii
3                       Q2_2                        jjjj
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    e.e.value('../recordid[1]', 'INT') As [recordid]
    ,e.e.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'NVARCHAR(100)') As [ElementName]
    ,e.e.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(100)') As [Value]
FROM @xml.nodes('/*/*/*') e(e)
WHERE
    e.e.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'NVARCHAR(100)') != 'recordid'
```